# How to zip list of files + append custom string to each file on Linux on the fly

Tags: linux, shell, gzip, 7zip

I need a Linux solution as I've figured out a way to do this on Windows by modifying a C# implementation but I am not sure where to start on Linux.  I would like to be able to do the following from the command line:

1. Run a command providing a list of files to be zipped, an output path, and a custom string
2. The custom string should be automatically appended to the end of the internal data of each file but not written to the original file. I want it all handled in-stream / in memory.
3. The data stream is fed to the zip utility and zip file is created at the output location with 0 compression (store only)

Explanation: this custom string is used as a watermark to uniquely identify the files in the zip.

Comment: At the moment, I think that this is too broad. It would be better to make an attempt at one of the parts and highlight where you're stuck with it.

Comment: Start writing some code

Comment: I found the solution shortly after I posted this.. I've solved the problem by using Mono to execute the C# code on Ubuntu. The library I'm using is SharpZip.. and I modified it to accept additional command line parameters and append the string to each file in-stream.